# C# Foreach iteration read to end of list

Tags: c#, selenium, foreach

I'm currently iterating through a list using foreach loop with a textfile, but when it reachs the end of the list it goes back on itself, so from line 1 to 10 then it goes from 10 to 1 instead of ending?

Example of code -

```
public static int lineint = 1;
```

Foreach function:

```
        foreach (String line in File.ReadLines(@"input.txt").Skip(lineint))
        {
            string[] data = line.Split(':');
            string query = data[0];
            string uri = data[1];



            if (driver.FindElements(By.Name("search")).Count != 0)
            {
                // exists
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys(search);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("uri")).SendKeys(uri + Keys.Enter);

                CheckResponse(line); //triggers function

            }
            else
            {
                driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                driver.Navigate().Refresh();
            }
        }
```

CheckResponse(line); function -

```
    private static void CheckResponse(string line)
    {

        if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='modal']/div/div/div/p[contains(text(), 'Search not found')]")).Count != 0)
        {


            Console.WriteLine(line + " - Failed Search");

            lineint = lineint + 1;

            foreachsearchfunc(); //function for the foreach loop

        }
        else
        {
            Console.Writeline("Success");
        }

    }
```

So what happens is for each function sends a request within the first line of the file then triggers checkresponse funciton, if check responses returns " Search not found " it retriggers the foreach with a + 1 on .skip, skipping the first line onto the second line and so fourth.

But what happens when it reaches the end of the list provided it runs back on its self, so example -

input =

```
Search1:Uri1
Search2:uri2
Search3:Uri3
```

process =

```
Search1:Uri1
Search2:uri2
Search3:Uri3
Search3:Uri3
Search2:uri2
Search1:Uri1
Search1:Uri1
Search2:uri2
...
```

and continues to loop the list back and fourth..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than these snippets. Try to simplify the conditions and remove Selenium from the equation, e.g. by hard-coding data. I strongly suspect you shouldn't be using recursion here, but it's not clear to me what you *want* to do or why you're currently calling your method recursively. I'm sure that if you can clarify your question, we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity I'll name your functions "each" and "check".

It would appear that this is happening:

1. You enter "each" and branch into the if statement which calls "check".
2. Check increments the start position, and calls "each" again.
3. "each" now executes its behaviour, and returns to "check".
4. "check" returns to the "each" from #1 and continues executing it.

Without knowing exactly how it should work, you can probably prevent this by adding `break;` on a new line after `CheckResponse(line);`

If exiting the loop depends on the "check" being successful or not, you should change it to return a boolean:

```
private static boolean CheckResponse(string line)
```

And then add `return true;` in the "success" part of the "if" and `return false;` in the "failed" part of the if. Then you can conditionally break in the "each" method:

```
if (CheckResponse(line))) // or `if (!CheckResponse(line))`, depending on what you need
{
    break;
}
```

---

In fact, can't you simplify what you're doing to this?:

```
foreach (String line in File.ReadLines(@"input.txt").Skip(lineint))
{
    string[] data = line.Split(':');
    string query = data[0];
    string uri = data[1];



    if (driver.FindElements(By.Name("search")).Count != 0)
    {
        // exists
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys(search);
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("uri")).SendKeys(uri + Keys.Enter);

        if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='modal']/div/div/div/p[contains(text(), 'Search not found')]")).Count == 0)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Success");
             break; // exit the loop
        }
    }
    else
    {
        driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
        driver.Navigate().Refresh();
    }
}
```